# MPI_Isend stuck sometime.(openmpi mutiple-thread)

Tags: mpi, openmpi

(First of all, I want to thank Hristo Iliev. He helps me a lot in my current MPI project.)

The problem is that MPI_Irecv will stuck sometimes (stuck probability is close to 1/2).  My program is more than 20,000 lines. So I cannot list it here.

The code where it stuck is that:

MPI id:0

```
MPI_Ssend(id=1,tag=1);
MPI_Ssend(id=1,tag=x);
MPI_Recv(id=1,tag=x+1);
```

MPI id:1

```
MPI_Recv(id=0,tag=1);
pthread_create(fun_A());

void fun_A()
{
    MPI_Recv(id=0,tag=x);
    MPI_Ssend(id=0,tag=x+1);
}
```

In order to debug it, I added some flags after each MPI functions. There flags include printf and write some flags to file.

Several points of my program are lited below.

1.(important)  When I run my mpi program in 1 machine using 2 cores, it is OK. But when I run it in 2 machines (each machine using 1 core), sometimes , in MPI id:1, MPI_Ssend(id=0,tag=x+1)(and MPI_wait()) is returned but MPI id:0 stuck at MPI_Recv(id=1,tag=x+1).

2.(important)  When MPI_Recv(id=1,tag=x+1);(MPI id:0) stucks, the first 2 MPI_functions in  MPI_id:1 should have finished. But sometimes there is no flags of MPI_id:1 at all, sometime there are flags of all 3 MPI functions of MPI id:1.

3.(important) There is no sender thread, when it stuck at MPI_Recv(id=1,tag=x+1); in MPI id:0.

4.vfork is used in my program to fork other jobs. MPI functions are not used in these jobs. These jobs use message queue to communicate with a thread in MPI_comm_world.

5.I enabled multiple-thread support while config. MPI_Init_thread(mutiple_thread support) is used to Init MPI. Ret-value of it is checked.

I do not what's going on about my program. I guess:

1. There is bug in openMPI
2. There is error in config.
3. There is bug in my program. (But if there is bug in my program, why it is OK when I run MPI at 1 machine using 2 cores but failed when at 2 machines each using 1 core).

Could anyone give me any hints?

the out put of ifconfig -a is:
One node ip is 10.1.1.112. The other is 10.1.1.113. The out put of ifconfig is exactly the same except ip-addr.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5E:2F:62:8A
          inet addr:10.1.1.113  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:da8:203:eb1:221:5eff:fe2f:628a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:5eff:fe2f:628a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3402577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:208064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:291778729 (278.2 MiB)  TX bytes:25343147 (24.1 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:5E:2F:62:8C
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:798595 (779.8 KiB)  TX bytes:798595 (779.8 KiB)
```

Comment: Could you please post the network configuration (the output of `ifconfig`) of the two nodes where your program is running.

Comment: Also, why on Earth are you calling `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Wait` immediately after when this is **exactly equivalent** to simply calling `MPI_Send`? The same applies to `MPI_Irecv` followed by `MPI_Wait`.

Comment: I have added the out put of ifconfig -a

Comment: The reason why I use MPI_Isend & MPI_Wait is I want to add debug flags after each MPI_function. In this way, I can get the infomation about the current position of my program.  Sometimes MPI_Send just copy data to buffer, then returned without wait the response of the receiver.

Comment: BTW, there are some other nodes in my cluster which use bridge connection (br0). I removed the interface of br0, then use -mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 to start the MPI. MPI also stuck in that kinds of node sometimes. The ip-addr of each node is assigned to eth0.

Comment: `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Isend` initiate exactly the same operation - the standard send which completes either when the message has been buffered or when the receiver has started receiving the message. If you want to make sure that only the latter is the case, you should send the message in synchronous mode using `MPI_Ssend` or `MPI_Issend`.

Comment: Oh...It is a big mistake. Now I have fixed it. But the problem is still there. Sometimes, sender and recever matched in id:tag but they all stucked.(eg.MPI id:0 stuck at MPI_Ssend(id=1,tag=1); MPI id:1 stuck at MPI_Recv(id=0,tag=1); ) Sometimes, only sender or recever stucked the other peer does not exist(eg.MPI id:0 stuck at MPI_Recv(id=1,tag=x+1);. But there is no flags of MPI id:1 at all!). It is too weird! I worked on it for 4 days. Is it possible that my program have bugs? Or, is there something wrong in network configuration?

Comment: Try attaching to the hanging ranks with GDB and examining the thread stacks to see where they hang. Or even better, use a parallel debugger such as TotalView, if you have access to one, as it makes things easier.

Comment: OK. Actually, I have TotalView for 1 month. But it is complicate to install and use. The datasheet is too long! So, I still use gdb. haha. Ok, I will try to install and use totalview right now. Thanks for your suggestions. Perhaps, it is the only way left.

Comment: I changed openmpi to mpich2. After the change, problem sloved. I don't know why. But, in a week, my program will be run in Tianhe 2. I must try everything to make the program better. Thanks for you help. :)